# MDX: Get parent of leaves of ragged hierarchy

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I working on report to display each country and how many reps and sales managers in this country for the measure of reps count I created by found the lowest level and by this query.

```
iif(IsLeaf([FF Hierarchy].[FF Hierarchy].currentmember),[Measures].[#Employees],null)
```

The problem is Sales manager isn't known level we can know this member is Sales manager when he is parent of rep in other meaning parent of the leaf 
I don't know how get this level.

This is my code:

```
   with member [#Reps1] as
     iif(IsLeaf([FF Hierarchy].[FF Hierarchy].currentmember),[Measures].[#Employees],null)
     member [# of rep1] as
     SUM(DESCENDANTS([FF Hierarchy].[FF Hierarchy].currentmember,0,SELF_AND_AFTER),[Measures].[#Reps1])

     SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[# of rep1] } ON COLUMNS,
     NON EMPTY { 
     ([FF Hierarchy].[Business Unit].[Business Unit].MEMBERS  )
     * Descendants([FF Hierarchy].[FF Hierarchy],1,self) 
     } ON ROWS 
     FROM [FFE Cube]
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Ordinal` property? It shows current level. 0 = ALL, 1 is under ALL etc.

Comment: the problem is sales manager level is not known, it is a dynamic level sometimes can be level 4, 3 or even 2 
that's why I want to get the parent of leaf member